# Sorting specific CSV column data in Python before output display

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting

I am trying to alphabetically sort a specific column of a CSV file and then write the output. The CSV has around 200 entries. Here's the code I've written so far but it just seems to display the data as it went in.

```
import operator
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
def write_output(data):
    with open('C:\\forex.csv', mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(["SYMBOL", "VOLATILITY","% CHANGE",""])
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

I want to tweak the code in such a way that the "SYMBOL" column should get alphabetically sorted before being written to the output CSV file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `data` as well?

Comment: assuming data is just a python list of list and symbol would be the first element in the sub lists have you tried `for row in sorted(data, key=lambda item: item[0]):`

Comment: Thanks Chris Doyle. Your technique solved the problem. Thanks immensely.

Comment: Why don't you use `pandas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sort your data before you start writing it. Assuming data is a list of lists and that symbol is the first element of each sublist then you can modify the line

`for row in data:`

to be

`for row in sorted(data, key=lambda item: item[0]):`

This will return a sorted representation of the data based on the first element in the sub lists and ordered from low to high

```py
import operator
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
def write_output(data):
    with open('C:\\forex.csv', mode='w', encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        writer = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        writer.writerow(["SYMBOL", "VOLATILITY","% CHANGE",""])
        for row in sorted(data, key=lambda item: item[0]): 
            writer.writerow(row)
```